# how to understand Artin-Rees lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I know this lemma is very important.it can be used to prove Krull Intersection Theorem.but I think maybe this is very difficult to understand.And I also do not know how to use this lemma.
[image]
 -
What is the most importance of this?
-how to understand the meaning of this lemma?

Comment: I find Atiyah and MacDonald's presentation very clear. What they call "Artin-Rees lemma" is Proposition 10.9, which is a very natural statement, and they formulate the statement you highlighted as a corollary (Corollary 10.10). (The fact that the corollary follows from the proposition is obvious.)

Comment: One way of thinking about this is, for a module $M$ and an ideal $I$, you have topology on $M$, called the $I$-adic topology. Artin-Rees says in the above situation, you have two topologies on $N$, the $I$-adic one and the one induced by the topology on $M$ and they are actually the same.

Comment: @Mohan thank you,this sounds interesting!

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard thank you.I will read this